# Services for recruiting Japanese research participants

Tags: users, research, recruitment

I've been asking everyone in my network, done Google searches, and checked StackExchange but still haven't found good answers.

I'm running a research study where I need to recruit 90 participants from Japan and 90 from the US for a 1.5 hour group discussion study on Zoom.

Do you know of any services/platforms where I could recruit Japanese user research participants (and even better, both US and Japanese participants)? I've been looking into Lancers, but I understand that most people on that website are freelancers.

Thank you for your help or any leads! :)

Comment: Hye Eureka, Im not sure if this is helpful but if you have the budget for a third party to run the study on your behalf, you can check Ipsos out (https://www.ipsos.com/en)

Comment: Thank you so much for the lead! I will check them out :)

Answer (score 2):

In the past I worked on several design and research projects for Japanese customers, and every time we connected and recruited with the help of local intermediaries and services.

The main challenges, from a Western perspective, were not only filling the gap between cultural differences and language barriers but also understanding which were the [UX standards for the Japanese market](https://blog.grio.com/2020/06/uxui-design-across-cultures-usa-japan.html).

So my suggestion is always go through a local service that can provide you with the support needed, my recommendation is [Crossfrontier](https://crossfrontier.com).

https://crossfrontier.com/en/service/ux_research_study/

Comment: Thank you Carlo! This is very helpful. I'll be sure to check this out. I appreciate your help.

Comment: you're welcome @EurekaFoong ! I didn't notice that you were Japanese, so you already know what I was talking about. Check also this website for agencies worldwide that can support your research needs http://www.uxalliance.com/ They also have another suggestion for Japan https://www.mitsue.co.jp/

Comment: Thanks again Carlo! I actually am new to Japan as well so these are very helpful. :)